# Drag and drop example - HTML5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to learn the drag and drop example from the WWWC ([here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/dnd.html#drag-data-store)) and I can get the list items to be removed from the original list when dragged away, but not appear in the new list. Any ideas why not? I have tried on Safari 5.1.1, Chrome 15, and Firefox 7.0.1.

```
    <head>
        <title>Drag 'N Drop</title>
    </head>

    <p>What fruits do you like?</p>
    <ol ondragstart="dragStartHandler(event)" ondragend="dragEndHandler(event)">    
     <li draggable="true" data-value="fruit-apple">Apples</li>
     <li draggable="true" data-value="fruit-orange">Oranges</li>
     <li draggable="true" data-value="fruit-pear">Pears</li>
    </ol>
    <script>
      var internalDNDType = 'text/plain'; // set this to something specific to your site
      function dragStartHandler(event) {
        if (event.target instanceof HTMLLIElement) {
          // use the element's data-value="" attribute as the value to be moving:
          event.dataTransfer.setData(internalDNDType, event.target.dataset.value);
          event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'; // only allow moves
        } else {
          event.preventDefault(); // don't allow selection to be dragged
        }
      }
      function dragEndHandler(event) {
        // remove the dragged element
        event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target);

      }
    </script>

    <p>Drop your favorite fruits below:</p>
    <div dropzone="move s:text/plain" ondrop="dropHandler(event)">
        <ol dropzone="move s:text/plain" ondrop="dropHandler(event)">
         <!-- don't forget to change the "text/x-example" type to something
         specific to your site -->
            <li>Bananas</li>
        </ol>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
    </div>
    <script>
      var internalDNDType = 'text/plain'; // set this to something specific to your site
      function dropHandler(event) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData(internalDNDType);
        if (data == 'fruit-apple') {
          li.textContent = 'Apples';
        } else if (data == 'fruit-orange') {
          li.textContent = 'Oranges';
        } else if (data == 'fruit-pear') {
          li.textContent = 'Pears';
        } else {
          li.textContent = 'Unknown Fruit';
        }
        event.target.appendChild(li);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at this example:
http://html5demos.com/drag#view-source

Comment: Here is a basic html 5 drag drop usage tutorial: http://www.dotnetobject.com/Thread-HTML5-Drag-and-Drop-Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.  First, your dropzone needs to cancel the event on drag over:

```
<ol dropzone="move s:text/plain" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event)">

function dragOverHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Second, your `dropHandler` handler function is going to get fired several times because the drop target, most of the time, is going to be an `li` element rather than the `ol` (and possibly also the `div`, but I ignored that element).  So either add code to only handle the event at the `ol`, or cancel the event in `dropHandler` [with `stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).

Finally, the default action (at least in Firefox, didn't check other browsers) when an item is dropped is to try and navigate to the URL represented by the `text/plain` value, so you should add some `event.preventDefault()` in likely places.  Here's an updated `dropHandler` function:

```
function dropHandler(event) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData(internalDNDType);
    if (data == 'fruit-apple') {
      li.textContent = 'Apples';
    } else if (data == 'fruit-orange') {
      li.textContent = 'Oranges';
    } else if (data == 'fruit-pear') {
      li.textContent = 'Pears';
    } else {
      li.textContent = 'Unknown Fruit';
    }
    event.target.appendChild(li);
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

[Here's my updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/H54CH/).

Comment: The example you provided still doesn't add the item to the list when you drop it. I deleted the <div> and <li> to make sure it was being dropped onto the ordered list, but still nothing

Comment: @Chris Yes it does, what browser did you try it in? (Firefox 7.0.1 here, and now 8.0 because it updated when I did help->about)

Comment: @Chris I think I might see what the problem is: the 'dragend` event gets fired whether or not there's a successful drop, so the element is removed if you drop somewhere which isn't your drop zone.  It might be easier to remove the source element in the `drop` event instead.

Comment: @Chris Did you get it working?  Did you look at my jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be that you also need to add a dragover listener to the drop area in order to allow the drop action to happen.

```
function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

  return false;
}
```

You have a detailed explanation in this step by step [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) (although the elements in that tutorial act as both draggable elements and drop areas)

However, Chris, as much as I am glad you are experimenting with the native HTML5 drag and drop feature please accept my humble opinion when I say that your code has way too many serious mistakes both at markup level and Javascript level. i.e. missing tags, closing tags that don't exist, wrong attribute namespaces, repeated listeners in chained elements, repeated variables inside the same scope, etc. I'd suggest to go through several code reviews first.

Comment: The code was given at the linked tutorial, so obviously not production level code, but given that it was provided by the organization that sets the HTML standard, I had assumed it would work at the very least.